# Отображения графика кластеризации методом k-средних

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, кластеризация

Есть датасет, по двум выборочным столбцам которого я хочу провести кластеризацию с помощью метода k-средних, но получаю ошибку:

> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

Код:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
wcss=[]

x=df.iloc[:,[4,80]].values
for i in range(1,11):
   kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', random_state=42)
   kmeans.fit(x)
   wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
   plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
   plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
   plt.ylabel('WCSS') 
   plt.show()
```

Comment: спасибо большущее))) такая незначительная ошибка оказывается)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас лишний отступ в коде. Отрисовку нужно делать после того, как вы собрали данные по всем вариантам кластеризации. На каждой итерации цикла у вас получается одно значение, нужно собрать их все для отрисовки:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', random_state=42)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

# отрисовка после того, как собраны все данные
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS') 
plt.show()
```

Кстати, не уверен, что с одним кластером не будет ругаться, мне кажется нужно от 2-х кластеров начинать пробовать.